# Missing required parameter for [Route: backoffice.role.show] [URI: role/{role}] [Missing parameter: role]

Tags: php, laravel

I have really been with something for hours that apparently according to what I have read is easy but I cannot realize it. I pass my code structure to you so that you can see it and at the end I tell you what the problem is and the error it throws.

**Controller: RoleController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Http\Requests\Role\StoreRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Vista index de Roles';
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('theme.backoffice.pages.role.create');  
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreRequest $request, Role $role)
    {
        $role = $role->store($request);
        return redirect()->route('backoffice.role.show'.$role);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Role $role)
    {
        return view('theme.backoffice.pages.role.show', [
          'role' => $role,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Role $role)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Role  $role
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Role $role)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**web.php/routes**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
//BACKOFFICE
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth'], 'as'=>'backoffice.'], function(){
    Route::resource('role', 'App\Http\Controllers\RoleController');
    });
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('theme.backoffice.layouts.admin')

@section('title','Crear rol')

@section('head')

@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="section">
    <p class="caption">Introduce los datos para crear un nuevo rol</p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
        <div id="basic-form" class="section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
                    <div class="card-panel">
                    <h4 class="header2">Crear rol</h4>
                        <div class="row">
                        
                            <form class="col s12" method="post" action="{{ route('backoffice.role.store') }}">

                                {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <div class="row">
                                    @error('name')
                                        <span style="color:red" class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
                                        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    @error('description')
                                        <span style="color:red" class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                                        <textarea name="description" class="materialize-textarea" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                                        <label for="email">Descripcion</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit">Guardar
                                                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('scripts-foot')

@endsection
```

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('theme.backoffice.layouts.admin')

@section('title','Clinic')

@section('head')

@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="section">
    <p class="caption"><strong>Rol: </strong>{{$role->name}}</p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
        <div id="basic-form" class="section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2">
                    <div class="card-panel">
                    <h4 class="header2">Usuarios con el rol de {{$role->name}}</h4>
                        <div class="row">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Raul</li>
                                <li>Tomas</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts-foot')

@endsection
```

I tell you what my code does.

1-we create a new role in the CREATE view and we give it save.

2-This travels to the store method and saves it in the database

3- the store method returns a redirection to the route of the SHOW method so that the new created role is shown in said view.

Error:: Missing required parameter for [Route: backoffice.role.show] [URI: role/{role}] [Missing parameter: role].

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong since I'm passing the required parameter to the path name in the store method when it does the redirect. This is about looking for a different resolution or do I have an error which I am not realizing? . thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `$role->store(...)` returning?

Comment: Thanks a lot! $ role-> store ($ request); it returns what enters by request but with a slug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `$role` is not received for `backoffice.role.show`.

You can pass the expecting role like (problem was you were appending with '.' instead of ','):

`return redirect()->route('backoffice.role.show', $role);`

If you want to expliclity define role, you can use alias like:

`return redirect()->route('backoffice.role.show', ['role' => $role]);`

**Edit For Store Method**

You could use the [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers) in `routes/web.php`.

```
public function store(Request $request){
   // Validation
   $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required']);
   // Storing
   $role = Role::create($request);
   return redirect()->route('backoffice.role.show', $role);
}
```

For more information, you can visit [Laravel Generating Url to Named Route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake when passing the code to you. I had it as redirect () -> route ('backoffice.role.show'. $ Role); because I was trying in various ways, but actually I always had the route in the way you indicated. Anyway, it keeps throwing me the same error.

Comment: could you `dd($role)` before passing to the route. I belive the issue might be because $role is empty.

Comment: If it's true, you're right! $ role arrives as null

Comment: Added an alternative way for Store method. If it helps, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: The problem was with my Role model. A lack of attention made me not see that in the storage method in said model I was missing writing "return" of the function. So it returned $ role as null. Thanks a lot! I would love to give an accepted answer but stackoverflow won't let me have a reputation yet.

Comment: All is well then :D